# Can I config postgresql to truncate long string automatically

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Say I defined a column email: varchar(100), when insert abnormal emails, the jdbc throws exception: value to long

I can truncate the abnormal values before insert, but there are too many columns like this, so I am looking for a config, column definition or something else, then postgresql can truncate by default

Comment: I think it is unlikely that something like this exists. If you are trying to insert something that is too long, you'll lose data. If you want to lose data, then you should be explicit by truncating it yourself.

Comment: You could try a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on each of the tables, looking at each of the many columns

Comment: Perhaps this is also a case for "Don't use varchar(n) by default": https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_varchar.28n.29_by_default